# Python multiprocessing pool never finishes

Tags: python

I am running the following (example) code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
  return x*x

pool = Pool(processes=4)
print pool.map(f, range(10))
```

However, the code never finishes. What am I doing wrong?

The line

```
pool = Pool(processes=4)
```

completes successfully, it appears to stop in the last line. Not even pressing ctrl+c interrupts the execution. I am running the code inside an ipython console in Spyder.

Comment: I am getting `from: can't read /var/mail/multiprocessing`. Anywhere to solve this so I can actually run your code?

Comment: Your code prints `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]` as it should. How do you execute it?

Comment: What does programm print? Try to put last two lines in if __name__ == '__main__':

Comment: When I run it it doesn't print anything, it just doesn't finish. Running it in ipython console as a part of Spyder if that matters.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue in Jupyter IPython Notebook

Comment: @parrowdice Don't remember exactly, I think what was missing was pool.close() and pool.join() calls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f(x):
    return x * x


def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=3)  # set the processes max number 3
    result = pool.map(f, range(10))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(result)
    print('end')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The key step is to call `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` after the processes finished. Otherwise the pool is not released.
Besides, you should create the pool in the main process by putting the codes within `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue for me (on a Windows machine). I can tell all the tasks have finished because the CPU usage drops to zero, but `pool.map` never gets resolved.

Comment: Try to optimize the code in the process function `f`. For example, check if all resources closed correctly.

Comment: @m93a I am also facing the same issue on my windows 10 pc. pool never finishes job and I have to kill notebook. Did you find any solution?

Comment: same here on windows 10 - I added `print(os.getoid())` in the function `f` but nothing got printed.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me either on windows 10. I found a solution; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is throwing the interpreter off into a thread producing factory for some reason.
You first need to stop all the threads are now running and there will be tons. If you bring up the task manager you will see tons of rogue *python.exe* tasks. To kill them in bulk try:

```
taskkill /F /IM python.exe
```

You would need to do the above a couple of times and make sure the task manager does not show anymore python.exe tasks. This will also kill you spyder instance. So make sure you save.

Now change your code to the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
  return x*x

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
   pool = Pool(4)
   print pool.map(f, range(10))
```

Note that I have removed the *processes* named argument.

Comment: It doesn't help. It enters what seems like an infinite loop in 'print pool.map(f, range(10))' line.

Comment: One interesting thing is also that it seems impossible to stop the evaluation by pressing ctrl+c.

Comment: That is correct I precisely used this to fix it. Wait let me see what I have tried explicitly.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't help either. Same behaviour as before.

Comment: If you are editing your script in Spyder make sure you save it first before you run it. I have that problem all the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105551/discussion-between-siphr-and-smeznaric).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) instead of accessing the `Pool` class directly.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def f(x):
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print(list(executor.map(f, range(10))))
```

Note that the subprocesses created by the `ProcessPoolExecutor` will need to run the script, so it's important that the script is saved to the computer, and that the code is [protected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45302590/22062869) by the `if __name__ == '__main__'` wrapper.

Comment: Also, the script should **not** be called "multiprocessing.py", as this will prevent the `multiprocessing` module from importing correctly.