# Finding the cause of a BrokenProcessPool in python's concurrent.futures

Tags: python, debugging, concurrent.futures

**In a nutshell**

I get a `BrokenProcessPool` exception when parallelizing my code with `concurrent.futures`. No further error is displayed. I want to find the cause of the error and ask for ideas of how to do that.

**Full problem**

I am using [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/concurrent.futures.html) to parallelize some code.

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    mapObj = pool.map(myMethod, args)
```

I end up with (and only with) the following exception:

```
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A child process terminated abruptly, the process pool is not usable anymore
```

Unfortunately, the program is complex and the error appears only after the program has run for 30 minutes. Therefore, I cannot provide a nice minimal example.

In order to find the cause of the issue, I wrapped the method that I run in parallel with a try-except-block:

```
def myMethod(*args):
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The problem remained the same and the except block was never entered. I conclude that the exception does not come from my code.

My next step was to write a custom `ProcessPoolExecutor` class that is a child of the original `ProcessPoolExecutor` and allows me to replace some methods with cusomized ones. I copied and pasted the original code of the method `_process_worker` and added some print statements.

```
def _process_worker(call_queue, result_queue):
    """Evaluates calls from call_queue and places the results in result_queue.
        ...
    """
    while True:
        call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
        if call_item is None:
            # Wake up queue management thread
            result_queue.put(os.getpid())
            return
        try:
            r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
        except BaseException as e:
                print("??? Exception ???")                 # newly added
                print(e)                                   # newly added
            exc = _ExceptionWithTraceback(e, e.__traceback__)
            result_queue.put(_ResultItem(call_item.work_id, exception=exc))
        else:
            result_queue.put(_ResultItem(call_item.work_id,
                                         result=r))
```

Again, the `except` block is never entered. This was to be expected, because I already ensured that my code does not raise an exception (and if everything worked well, the exception should be passed to the main process).

Now I am lacking ideas how I could find the error. The exception is raised here:

```
def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    with self._shutdown_lock:
        if self._broken:
            raise BrokenProcessPool('A child process terminated '
                'abruptly, the process pool is not usable anymore')
        if self._shutdown_thread:
            raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after shutdown')

        f = _base.Future()
        w = _WorkItem(f, fn, args, kwargs)

        self._pending_work_items[self._queue_count] = w
        self._work_ids.put(self._queue_count)
        self._queue_count += 1
        # Wake up queue management thread
        self._result_queue.put(None)

        self._start_queue_management_thread()
        return f
```

The process pool is set to be broken here:

```
def _queue_management_worker(executor_reference,
                             processes,
                             pending_work_items,
                             work_ids_queue,
                             call_queue,
                             result_queue):
    """Manages the communication between this process and the worker processes.
        ...
    """
    executor = None

    def shutting_down():
        return _shutdown or executor is None or executor._shutdown_thread

    def shutdown_worker():
        ...

    reader = result_queue._reader

    while True:
        _add_call_item_to_queue(pending_work_items,
                                work_ids_queue,
                                call_queue)

        sentinels = [p.sentinel for p in processes.values()]
        assert sentinels
        ready = wait([reader] + sentinels)
        if reader in ready:
            result_item = reader.recv()
        else:                               #THIS BLOCK IS ENTERED WHEN THE ERROR OCCURS
            # Mark the process pool broken so that submits fail right now.
            executor = executor_reference()
            if executor is not None:
                executor._broken = True
                executor._shutdown_thread = True
                executor = None
            # All futures in flight must be marked failed
            for work_id, work_item in pending_work_items.items():
                work_item.future.set_exception(
                    BrokenProcessPool(
                        "A process in the process pool was "
                        "terminated abruptly while the future was "
                        "running or pending."
                    ))
                # Delete references to object. See issue16284
                del work_item
            pending_work_items.clear()
            # Terminate remaining workers forcibly: the queues or their
            # locks may be in a dirty state and block forever.
            for p in processes.values():
                p.terminate()
            shutdown_worker()
            return
        ...
```

It is (or seems to be) a fact that a process terminates, but I have no clue why. Are my thoughts correct so far? **What are possible causes that make a process terminate without a message? (Is this even possible?) Where could I apply further diagnostics? Which questions should I ask myself in order to come closer to a solution?**

I am using python 3.5 on 64bit Linux.

Comment: i got this error, and this post cleared up my problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900366/all-example-concurrent-futures-code-is-failing-with-brokenprocesspool

Comment: I got same error, the multi-process exit code is -11. While the same function work fine in multi-threads.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I was able to get as far as possible:

I changed the `_queue_management_worker` method in my changed `ProcessPoolExecutor` module such that the exit code of the failed process is printed:

```
def _queue_management_worker(executor_reference,
                             processes,
                             pending_work_items,
                             work_ids_queue,
                             call_queue,
                             result_queue):
    """Manages the communication between this process and the worker processes.
        ...
    """
    executor = None

    def shutting_down():
        return _shutdown or executor is None or executor._shutdown_thread

    def shutdown_worker():
        ...

    reader = result_queue._reader

    while True:
        _add_call_item_to_queue(pending_work_items,
                                work_ids_queue,
                                call_queue)

        sentinels = [p.sentinel for p in processes.values()]
        assert sentinels
        ready = wait([reader] + sentinels)
        if reader in ready:
            result_item = reader.recv()
        else:                               

            # BLOCK INSERTED FOR DIAGNOSIS ONLY ---------
            vals = list(processes.values())
            for s in ready:
                j = sentinels.index(s)
                print("is_alive()", vals[j].is_alive())
                print("exitcode", vals[j].exitcode)
            # -------------------------------------------


            # Mark the process pool broken so that submits fail right now.
            executor = executor_reference()
            if executor is not None:
                executor._broken = True
                executor._shutdown_thread = True
                executor = None
            # All futures in flight must be marked failed
            for work_id, work_item in pending_work_items.items():
                work_item.future.set_exception(
                    BrokenProcessPool(
                        "A process in the process pool was "
                        "terminated abruptly while the future was "
                        "running or pending."
                    ))
                # Delete references to object. See issue16284
                del work_item
            pending_work_items.clear()
            # Terminate remaining workers forcibly: the queues or their
            # locks may be in a dirty state and block forever.
            for p in processes.values():
                p.terminate()
            shutdown_worker()
            return
        ...
```

Afterwards I looked up the meaning of the exit code:

```
from multiprocessing.process import _exitcode_to_name
print(_exitcode_to_name[my_exit_code])
```

whereby `my_exit_code` is the exit code that was printed in the block I inserted to the `_queue_management_worker`. In my case the code was -11, which means that I ran into a segmentation fault. Finding the reason for this issue will be a huge task but goes beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using macOS, there is a known issue with how some versions of macOS uses forking that's not considered fork-safe by Python in some scenarios. The workaround that worked for me is to use no_proxy environment variable.

Edit ~/.bash_profile and include the following (it might be better to specify list of domains or subnets here, instead of *)

```
no_proxy='*'
```

Refresh the current context

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

My local versions the issue was seen and worked around are: Python 3.6.0 on
macOS 10.14.1 and 10.13.x

Sources: 
[Issue 30388](https://bugs.python.org/issue30385)  
[Issue 27126](https://bugs.python.org/issue27126)

Comment: Same issue with MacOS 10.14.6 (18G87) and Python 3.7.2