# What's the meaning of runfile in Spyder

Tags: spyder, pypdf

I can't interpret the error message when trying to use PyPDF2 in WinPython/Spyder

Error message:

> In [3]: runfile('C:/Users/User/Downloads/WPy64-3720/pdf2text.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Downloads/WPy64-3720')

Code:

```
import PyPDF2
path="C:\\Users\User\Downloads\WPy64-3720\soln.pdf"
text="C:\\Users\User\Downloads\WPy64-3720\Soln.text"
pdf_file = open(path, 'rb')
text =""
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
c = read_pdf.numPages
for i in range(c):
    page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
    text+=(page.extractText())
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a complete error message. Do you have the remaining part?

Comment: This is the complete error message on Spyder/WinPython.

Comment: Try changing all \ to `/`. The \ in a string is an escape character.

Comment: Tried the following: 

`path=r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\WPy64-3720\soln.pdf"  
 text=r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\WPy64-3720\soln.text"`
Still get the following error message, and no text file gets created: 

_In [16]: runfile('C:/Users/User/Downloads/WPy64-3720/pdf2text.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Downloads/WPy64-3720')_

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That's not an error message. `runfile` is the command used by Spyder to run your code in the IPython console.

If you're not seeing anything else is because you haven't printed anything in your code. For instance, adding this line to your code

```
print('Hello world!')
```

will show a `Hello world` printed below `runfile`.