# Python error when running script more than once: module '__main__' has no attribute '__spec__'

Tags: python, macos

Long time (very grateful) user of SO, but first time hitting something I can't seem to find a pre-existing answer for. So here goes my first plea for wisdom to the hive mind.

I hit this problem while implementing some Python multiprocessing routines in a code of mine. I tracked it all down to the following MWE (which actually has nothing to do with multiprocessing anymore):

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dir(sys.modules['__main__']))
```

If I put this in `tmp.py`, and run it from an ipython terminal (i.e. `run tmp`) a first time, it works fine and prints:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__nonzero__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'sys']
```

If I run it again **in the same terminal**, in prints:

```
['__builtins__', '__file__', '__name__', '__nonzero__', 'sys']
```

The fact that `__spec__` is not available the second time around triggers the following error when `multiprocessing.Pool` tries to access it:

```
----> 6     print(sys.modules['__main__'].__spec__ is None)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__spec__'
```

There are a lot of questions about this error message out there, but none seem to apply to my case as far as I can tell. I am not using any IDE or anything fancy - just a regular OSX terminal. Most people seem to encounter this bug when using the `multiprocessing` package (like me), which is often blamed for it (e.g. [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue42949)). But the above MWE makes it clear that something (i.e. the content of `__spec__`) is not constant between successive runs of a given script in an ipython terminal.

Questions: is this normal Python behavior ? Am I missing anything obvious ?

**Edit (to clarify and anticipate possible replies):**
The suggestion to hard-code `__spec__ = None` to avoid the error, as suggested e.g. [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720153/python-multiprocessing-error-attributeerror-module-main-has-no-attribute), does work. But I am wary to do this as I do not understand the implications.

What is this `__spec__` element ? Why is it not stable when I run the MWE above twice in a row ? What are the implications of setting it by hand ? Is there anyway that this can blow-up on a different OS ?

Running Python 3.8.5, ipython 7.20.0 on Mac OS 10.15.

Comment: for checking any attribute of a module or object, try dir of it like `dir(sys.modules['__main__'])` it will give you allowed  attribute/operation that you can apply

Comment: @tard - thanks for the suggestion. I updated the MWE accordingly.

Comment: I have not found an answer, but I am having a hunch it has something to do with how ipython handles (some?) `None` values. The 3 values, which are culled after the second run are `__loader__`, `__spec__` and `__package__`. All these have `None` set as their values beforehand