# Python concurrent.futures: ProcessPoolExecutor fail to work

Tags: python, time, concurrency, subprocess, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to use the ProcessPoolExecutor method but it fails.
Here is an example(calculation of the big divider of two numbers) of a failed use.
I don't understand what the mistake is

```
def gcd(pair):
    a, b = pair
    low = min(a, b)
    for i in range(low, 0, -1):
        if a % i == 0 and b % i == 0:
            return i

numbers = [(1963309, 2265973), (2030677, 3814172),
           (1551645, 2229620), (2039045, 2020802)]
start = time()
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
results = list(pool.map(gcd, numbers))
end = time()
print('Took %.3f seconds' % (end - start))
```

BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All example concurrent.futures code is failing with "BrokenProcessPool"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900366/all-example-concurrent-futures-code-is-failing-with-brokenprocesspool)

Comment: The solution shown there does not solve my problem.It still raises the error

Answer (score 5):

Change your code to look like this, and it will work:

```
from time import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
def gcd(pair):
    a, b = pair
    low = min(a, b)
    for i in range(low, 0, -1):
        if a % i == 0 and b % i == 0:
            return i

numbers = [(1963309, 2265973), (2030677, 3814172),
           (1551645, 2229620), (2039045, 2020802)]

def main():
    start = time()
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    results = list(pool.map(gcd, numbers))
    end = time()
    print('Took %.3f seconds' % (end - start))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On systems that support `fork()` this isn't necessary, because your script is imported just once, and then each process started `ProcessPoolExecutor` will already have a copy of objects in your global namespace like the `gcd` function.  Once they're forked, they go through a bootstrap process whereby they start running their target function (in this case a worker process loop that accepts jobs from the process pool executor) and they *never* return to the original code in your main module from which they were forked.

By contrast, if you're using the `spawn`-based processes which are the default on Windows and OSX, a new process must be started up from scratch for each worker process, and if they must re-*import* your module.  However, if your module does something like `ProcessPoolExecutor` directly in the module body, without guarding it like `if __name__ == '__main__':`, then there is no way for them to import your module without also starting a new `ProcessPoolExecutor`.  So this error you're getting is essentially guarding you from creating an infinite process bomb.

This is mentioned in the docs for [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor):

> The `__main__` module must be importable by worker subprocesses. This means that `ProcessPoolExecutor` will not work in the interactive interpreter.

But they don't really make clear why that is or what it means for the `__main__` module to be "importable".  When you write a simple script in Python and run it like `python foo.py`, your script `foo.py` is loaded with a module name of `__main__`, as opposed to a module named `foo` which you get if you `import foo`.  For it to be "importable" in this case really means, importable without major side-effects like spawning new processes.

Comment: What if I have class and a method inside of the class uses a  ProcessPool? I have tried that but it's not working...

Comment: @AkashTadwai Please open a new question, without details I couldn't tell you.