# Broken Process Pool Error - Concurrent Futures

Tags: python

I am running some code with Python's `concurrent.futures` module, and I am having issues running it. I am on Windows 10 and using Python 3.8. I am trying to run a simulation, which is running fine on the Mac that my friend has. I tried setting

`Max Workers = 1, :cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:`
as was suggested in  another thread, but it also also failed. I am kind of out of ideas.

The stack trace looks like this—

```
 Error Description: BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.

Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lotfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Lotfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lotfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 233, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "C:\Users\Lotfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 116, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'runTest' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in doit2
  File "C:\Users\Lotfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 484, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Lotfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\Users\Lotfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\Lotfi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

Comment: A possible duplicate of—https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900366/all-example-concurrent-futures-code-is-failing-with-brokenprocesspool

Comment: Good point, i added :

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doit2()
, but forgot to show it here, it still messes things up. I also saved it, as was recommended.

Comment: I may have this fixed:

def doit2():
    dists = df['dist']
    n1s = df['n1']
    n2s = df['n2']
    alphas = df['alpha']
    
    start = time.perf_counter()
    # with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        results = executor.map(runTest, dists, n1s, n2s, alphas)
        for r in results:
            # print(r)
            output.append(r)
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)")

if __name__ == '__doit2__':
     doit2()

At least the error is gone