# concurrent futur object block forever

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I try to understand concurrency from David Beazley talks. But when executing the server and client and try to submit the number 20 fro client, is seem that the futur object block forever when calling futur.result(). I can't understand why:

```
# server.py
# Fib microservice

from socket import *
from fib import fib
from threading import Thread
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool

pool = Pool(4)

def fib_server(address):
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(address)
    sock.listen(5)
    while True:
        client, addr = sock.accept()
        print("Connection", addr)
        Thread(target=fib_handler, args=(client,), daemon=True).start()

def fib_handler(client):
    while True:
        req = client.recv(100)
        if not req:
            break
        n = int(req)
        future = pool.submit(fib, n)
        #Next line will block!!!!
        result = future.result()
        resp = str(result).encode('ascii') + b'\n'
        client.send(resp)
    print("Closed")

fib_server(('',25000))
```

```
#client.py
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost',25000))
while True:
    num=input("number?")
    s.send(str(num).encode('ascii') + b'\n')
    res = s.recv(1000)
    print('res:',res)
```

**server>** python server.py

**client>** python client.py

We see in order:

**server>** Connection ('127.0.0.1', 57876)

**client>** number?20

**server>**[freeze]

Answer (score 0):

Finally this post help me to solve the problem: [All example concurrent.futures code is failing with "BrokenProcessPool"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900366/all-example-concurrent-futures-code-is-failing-with-brokenprocesspool).

"Under Windows, it is important to protect the main loop of code to avoid recursive spawning of subprocesses when using processpoolexecutor or any other parallel code which spawns new processes.

Basically, all your code which creates new processes must be under if **name** == '**main**': , for the same reason you cannot execute it in interpreter."